# Buid.gradle error trying to use kotlin.plugin.serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to follow this basic tutorial from [Android Dev Codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-getting-data-internet?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-5-pathway-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-getting-data-internet#7).

I'm following the tutorial exactly as it is, but I get this error when trying to Sync my build.gradle:

```
Cause: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleSubplugin: org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.gradle.SerializationGradleSubplugin not a subtype
```

My build.gradle file is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

    //User plugins
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization" version "1.7.21"
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.testeworkmanager'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testeworkmanager"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    //User dependencies

    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:0.8.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.0"
}
```

I tryed for 1 hour to google and understand what's happening, but can't figure what I'm doing wrong. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73018912/gradle-fails-after-kotlin-serialization-plugin-update-to-1-7-10, maybe there is some other piece of your build that has another version for the Kotlin plugin (it should be aligned)

Comment: You were right. Actually I had read that post before, but I coudn't figure where the "kotlin("kjvm") version 1.6.10" was. Now I know it's in the project's build.gradle. Updated it there and it's all working. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure both versions are the same **1.6.10** in this case in **project build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

Then in **module build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Joffrey pointed out, there was a line with `'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false` in my **project's** `build.gradle`. Changed it to 1.7.10 and it's all working.